# Django Admin: How to use the button to move to the selected URL?

Tags: html, django, django-admin

I am very new to Django and trying to make my first project. I find it difficult to use the buttons I created to move to the selected URL.

Let's say my app is called `TestForms` and my models are: `Patients`, `General`, `PST` and `ERBT`. I would like to create two buttons - 'Previous' and 'Next' - which will be used to go to previous/next forms respectively. I try to do so using admin templates in django.

**NOTE**: I know changing built-in templates are not a very good idea, I will create new html file to extend this templates before doing changes on the server. For now I am doing it locally on my computer.

In `submit_line.html` I created two new buttons and they are like so:

```
{% if show_save_and_go_to_next_form %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Next' %}" class="default" name="_gotonextform">{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_go_to_previous_form %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Previous' %}" class="default" name="_gotopreviousform">{% endif %}
```

This gives me two good-looking buttons on the site.

But these are just saving the results (working like 'Save' button), but not redirecting me to the next form as I would like to. When I am adding a new patient (`admin/TestForms/patient/add/`), after clicking on 'Next' I would like the server to save this patient and redirect me to `admin/TestForms/general/add/` to be able to fullfil the next form, then save the changes and move on to `admin/TestForms/PST/add/`and so on.

I know I have to add the `<a href="..."> </a>` anchor, but I tried multiple times with different approaches and nothing worked. When I try to use `<a href ...>`, the button disappears. Also it is difficult for me to figure out how to move from one form to another and to disable the 'Previous' button on the first form and the 'Next' button on the last form.

Any suggestions how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect needs to be done in your view, not in the template.

```py
def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # your code ...
    if request.POST.get('_gotonextform'):
        return redirect('admin/TestForms/general/add/')
    else:
        # do whatever you like if any other button was clicked
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me ... Should I refer to this view in my `model.py` or `admin.py` file? Moreover, do you know how to change the URL dynamically, so that I can refer to `general` form if I am on `patient` form and to refer to `PST` form if I am on `general` form etc?